# How to jump between markdown code chunk fence?

Tags: filetype-markdown, jump

Is there a way to jump between beginning and end of a markdown based code chunk?

I know I can use `/` to search for the code chunk markers (e.g. ```` /``` ````) but I was hoping there was a way to do like we can do with `%` for open/closing parenthesis or I understand there is some tag functionality too - but not sure if it can be adopted for the below use case.

````
```{r} (<< I want to be able to jump between here and ...)

Some code text

Some more code text

``` (<< here)
````

Comment: Those things are called "fenced code blocks". Anyway, did you even consider taking a look at `:help %`? It has all the needed pointers.

Comment: Why would I consider looking at the specific % help page? There are 100s of help page topics — how would I know to start there?
It’s unclear if your comment is serious or  if you’re trying  at all to be helpful.

Comment: Because you essentially want `%` for fenced code blocks. From there, the first logical step would be to see if `%` can be tweaked some way or another and… where else to look than `:help %`?

Comment: I gave % as example of a functionality to mimic. I also referenced \. 

As you know from your rating there are many ways to do things in vim including remapping key bindings. 

Furthermore different users have different level of familiarity with vim and vims functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [matchit](https://github.com/chrisbra/matchit) plugin that comes in modern version of Vim.

You can install it with:

```
packadd! matchit
```

Or from GitHub and vim-plug with:

```
Plug 'chrisbra/matchit'
```

To match the ```` ``` ```` fence you have to add ```` ```.\+:``` ```` to `b:match_words`

You can do that by adding the following code into: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`

````
if match(b:match_words, '```') == -1
  let b:match_words = b:match_words . ',```.\+:```'
endif
````

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful and straightforward answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad I could help you :-)